# foreach checkbox to keep POST values

Tags: php, foreach

I've attempted to store POST values into selected checkboxes, I'm having some problem with it storing data after the form is submitted. This is what I have:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Categories:</legend>
            <?php $sql3 = 'SELECT id, name FROM category'; 
                    foreach ($dbConnection->query($sql3) as $category) { ?>
            <div>       
                <label for="category<?php echo($category['id']);?>">
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" id="category<?php echo($category['id']); ?>" value="<?php echo($category['id']); ?>"
                <?php if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == $category['id']) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>
                <?php echo($category['name']); ?></label>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
```

Any chance someone can lend a hand with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your if statement to this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['categories']) && in_array($category['id'],$_POST['categories'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?>>
        <?php echo($category['name']); ?></label>
```